# Statistics of a Gaussian random variable with the floor function transformation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Suppose $X$ is a Gaussian random variable, i.e., $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma)$. Let $Y$ be defined as $Y=\lfloor X \rfloor$, where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denotes the floor function (greatest integer lesser or equal than $X$). It can be seen from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247966/calculating-probability-of-floored-log-normal-distribution) that $$P(Y=y)=P(y\le X< y+1)=P(X<y+1)-P(X\le y)\\ =\Phi\left(\frac{y+1-\mu}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\right) \\ =\frac{1}{2}\left[1+\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{y+1-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]-\frac{1}{2}\left[1+\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]$$ where $\Phi(\cdot$) is the CDF for standard Gaussian and $\operatorname{erf}(\cdot)$ is the error function.

**I have two questions:**

(1) Is $Y$ a regular discrete random variable? Or it does not have a standard expression (i.e., does it belong to any families of distributions)?

(2) **More importantly**, what is the mean and variance of random variable $Y$?

Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "regular"?  It is a discrete random variable taking values in the integers, with a rather unpleasant probability mass function.

Comment: @RobertIsrael What I want to say is if $Y$ can be reduced to a pleasant form or belongs to any families of distributions. But more importantly, I'm interested in its mean and variance.

Comment: Same question asked recently at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278040/finding-the-mean-and-variance-of-a-distribution/278164#278164.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that you can write $X = \lfloor X \rfloor + \{X\}$, where $\{X\}$ is the fractional part of $X$.  Using the Poisson summation formula, I get (if I'm not mistaken)

$$ \mathbb E\lfloor X \rfloor = \mu - \mathbb E \{X\} = \mu - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{j=1}^\infty e^{-2\pi^2\sigma^2 j^2} \frac{\sin(2\pi j \mu)}{j} $$

Comment: +1. Note that if $\mu$ is an integer or half an integer then this is exactly $\mu -\frac12$ for whatever $\sigma^2$, and that unless $\sigma^2$ is small then $\mu -\frac12$ is a  good approximation for whatever $\mu$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a way to calculate or approximate the variance?

Comment: I tried to calculate myself to get the result you provided, but so far no success. Could you please show more steps on how to get it?